# How remove first start configuration in Windows 8/10

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10

In my firm, we have to use tablets on Windows 8.1 with Bing (or 10 later) - so yes, retail version, not professionnal.

The problem is, on the first start, Windows asks about Microsoft account for the store, colors of the account, name of the account, etc... Its take about 30 minutes to have the desktop for the first time.

I would like to know if it's possible to bypass this step ? I can imagine for example, an usb key which will write in files to configure automaticly this step, and after reboot : the Desktop ! If we can install some softs during the same time, it could be the best ! In fact, how avoid that : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUiV0DFS6Gc

The main problem is that : each tablet have its own Windows Serial Number. So we can't just use Ghost, make an iso and deploy on all our tablets.

PS : I don't speak about the licence number screen, all tablets are already its own serial number...

Comment: Someone speak about autounattend.xml but I'm not sure to understand...

Comment: Sign into a microsoft account and it'll just sync your settings.

Comment: I want to remove all the menu. And how tablets will works with only one account for hundreds of tablets ?

Comment: If your deployment is that large you should be using volume licencing and disk images.

Comment: I though about that, but we buy tablets with Windows on it (Product from Acer). Buy Volume licence means buy a licence twice.